Why are outputs (altitude and vertical velocity) still unstable (goes to negative infinity) after 2d Kalman filtering GY86 data?
I am using MS5611 in GY86 and ESP32 Dev kit to get the vertical velocity and altitude after running a 2d Kalman filter to it. (I modified the code from episode 19 of Carbon Aeronautics drone playlist). The results however are very bad, I couldn't reach those 2 values around 0, the integral summing is so bad the plot is a straight down line to infinity. When I lift the sensor up, the values are recorded but returns to 0 slowly, very slow. I tried tuning the Kalman filter by adjusting Q, R and Kalman gain, but it won't turn stable like in Carbon Aeronautic's video 1.
#include <Wire.h>
#include <MS5611.h>
float RateRoll, RatePitch, RateYaw;
float AngleRoll, AnglePitch;
float AccX, AccY, AccZ;
float AccZInertial;
float LoopTimer;
float AltitudeBarometer, AltitudeBarometerStartUp;
int RateCalibrationNumber;
#include <BasicLinearAlgebra.h>
using namespace BLA;
float AltitudeKalman, VelocityVerticalKalman;
BLA::Matrix<2,2> F; BLA::Matrix<2,1> G;
BLA::Matrix<2,2> P; BLA::Matrix<2,2> Q;
BLA::Matrix<2,1> S; BLA::Matrix<1,2> H;
BLA::Matrix<2,2> I; BLA::Matrix<1,1> Acc;
BLA::Matrix<2,1> K; BLA::Matrix<1,1> R;
BLA::Matrix<1,1> L; BLA::Matrix<1,1> M;
BLA::Matrix<1,1> inv_L = Inverse(L);
MS5611 ms5611;
void kalman_2d(void){
  Acc = {AccZInertial};
  S=F*S+G*Acc;
  P=F*P*~F+Q;
  L=H*P*~H+R;
  K=P*~H*inv_L;
  M={AltitudeBarometer};
  S=S+K*(M-H*S);
  AltitudeKalman=S(0,0); 
  VelocityVerticalKalman=S(1,0); 
  P=(I-K*H)*P;
}
double referencePressure;
void checkSettings()
{
  Serial.print("Oversampling: ");
  Serial.println(ms5611.getOversampling());
}
void baro(void){
  long realPressure = ms5611.readPressure();
  float AltitudeBarometer = ms5611.getAltitude(realPressure, referencePressure) * 100;
}
void gyro_signals(void) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x1A);
  Wire.write(0x05);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x1C);
  Wire.write(0x10);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x3B);
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
  Wire.requestFrom(0x68,6);
  int16_t AccXLSB = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  int16_t AccYLSB = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  int16_t AccZLSB = Wire.read() << 8 |  Wire.read();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x1B); 
  Wire.write(0x8);
  Wire.endTransmission();                                                   
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x43);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0x68,6);
  int16_t GyroX=Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();
  int16_t GyroY=Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();
  int16_t GyroZ=Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();
  RateRoll=(float)GyroX/65.5;
  RatePitch=(float)GyroY/65.5;
  RateYaw=(float)GyroZ/65.5;
  AccX=(float)AccXLSB/4096 - 0.1;
  AccY=(float)AccYLSB/4096 + 0.05;
  AccZ=(float)AccZLSB/4096 + 0.025;
  AngleRoll=atan(AccY/sqrt(AccX*AccX+AccZ*AccZ))*1/(3.142/180);
  AnglePitch=-atan(AccX/sqrt(AccY*AccY+AccZ*AccZ))*1/(3.142/180);
}
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  referencePressure = ms5611.readPressure();
  checkSettings();
  delay(2000);
  Wire.setClock(400000);
  Wire.begin();
  delay(250);
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68); 
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  for (RateCalibrationNumber=0; RateCalibrationNumber<2000; RateCalibrationNumber ++) {
    baro();
    AltitudeBarometerStartUp+=AltitudeBarometer; 
    delay(1); 
  }
  AltitudeBarometerStartUp/=2000;
  F = {1, 0.004,
            0, 1};  
  G = {0.5*0.004*0.004,
            0.004};
  H = {1, 0};
  I = {1, 0,
           0, 1};
  Q = G * ~G*10.0f*10.0f;
  R = {30*30};
  P = {0, 0,
           0, 0};
  S = {0,
           0};
           LoopTimer=micros();
}

void loop()
{
   gyro_signals();
  AccZInertial=-sin(AnglePitch*(3.142/180))*AccX+cos(AnglePitch*(3.142/180))*sin(AngleRoll*    
  (3.142/180))* AccY+cos(AnglePitch*(3.142/180))*cos(AngleRoll*(3.142/180))*AccZ;   
  AccZInertial=(AccZInertial-1)*9.81*100;
  baro();
  AltitudeBarometer-=AltitudeBarometerStartUp;
  kalman_2d();
  Serial.print("Altitude [m]:");
  Serial.print(AltitudeKalman/100);
  Serial.print(" Vertical velocity [m/s]:");
  Serial.println(VelocityVerticalKalman/100);
  while (micros() - LoopTimer < 4000); 
  LoopTimer=micros();                 
}


Any help would be appreciated. In his video he used the BMP280, while here I use MS5611, integrated in the GY86 sensor. If there is no way to get around this instability, will adding a PID controller stabilize this filter?
1    Carbon Aeronautics, Belgium. 19|Combine an accelerometer and barometer to measure altitude (2023). Accessed June. 30, 2024. [Online Video]. Available: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZevJyabMdI

MS5611 sensor should be correctly initialized. Check the pressure and temperature readings separately before using them in the Kalman filter.

@tepalia  I tried that before with the initializing code. It took about 20 more seconds for the readings to start appearing, and it's still unstable. Without the initializing (the code above) there is no need for 20 seconds and the filter still unstable
